# Why is Texmaker not refreshing the pdf?

Tags: pdf, latex, pdfviewer, texmaker

I am changing a LaTeX document in Texmaker and apparently the pdf does not get updated and I don't know why. I have as quick Build pdflatex + view pdf.

I am using Texmaker version 4.4.1 in Windows 7.

Before I was using the same tex file in another version of Texmaker and it worked, but know that I am trying to change things in the new version it doesn't.

It doesn't matter what I change in the latex file, it won't show any errors or anything while compiling, and when finished there is no change in the pdf at all.

Do you know what could be the cause for this issue?
Thank you very much to everyone!

Jorge

Comment: Consider using https://www.overleaf.com/